# Divide amount of a float over x numbers of variables

Tags: php, divide

I would like to divide a total amount (for example 4.45) over a dynamic number of variables (for example 4. The sum of the variables should always be the total of the total-amount.

- var1 = 1.11
- var2 = 1.11
- var3 = 1.11
- var4 = 1.12

if you divide by 4 you will get 1,1125 with a round(1.1125, 2) You will get 1.11. And 4 * 1.11 = 4.44. The remaining 0,01 can be added to the last number of vars so it will be 1.12.

Comment: 1. what did you try? 2. should it just be divided by 4 and can the numbers be the exact same, or do you want it to be 4 random numbers that in total reach 4.55?

Comment: If we divide `4.55` by `4`, we will have four `1.1375` s then each of your four variables will be the same number. So, is there any condition to not allow this?

Comment: if you divide by 4 you will get 1,1125 with a round(1.1125, 2) You will get 1.11. And 4 * 1.11 = 4.44. The remaining 0,01 can be added to the last number of vars so it will be 1.12.

Comment: You should add that into your question as a requirement. Don't make people look in the comments to figure out what you need. Helping us understand will help you in the end.

Comment: Also @ParthapratimNeog is correct: `4.55 / 4 = 1.1375`. So now I'm really confused.

Comment: True my fault I added the wrong number as example. I've changed it to 4.45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote you a function which does almost exactly what you want (I return an array). You can give in an amount and the number of vars you want to get returned. It always rounds to 2 decimals

```
<?php
function divideAmount($amount, $numberOfVars){

    $values = [];

    $dividedAmount = $amount/$numberOfVars;

    for($i=1; $i<=$numberOfVars; $i++){
        $values[] = round($dividedAmount,2);
    }

    $newAmount = 0;
    foreach($values as $value){
        $newAmount += $value;   
    }

    if($newAmount != $amount){
        $amountLeft = $amount - $newAmount; 
        $values[$numberOfVars-1] += $amountLeft;
    }

    return $values;
}


$values = divideAmount(4.45, 4);

var_dump($values);
```

Comment: Thanks Daan! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_fill()` for this:

```
$tot   = 4.45;   # sum total
$n     = 4;      # addends number

$values = array_fill( 0, $n-1, round( $tot/$n,2 ) );
$values[ $n-1 ] = round( $tot - array_sum( $values ),2 );

print_r( $values );
echo array_sum($values) . PHP_EOL;
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.11
    [1] => 1.11
    [2] => 1.11
    [3] => 1.12
)
4.45
```

<kbd>**[phpFiddle demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kp97-vz12)**</kbd>

First you fill an array of *n-1* items with rounded division of total  by dynamic number, then you add last items subtracting the sum of existing items to total.

Answer (score -1):

1) Use an array rather than separate variables
2) Count and sum the array